# How to change development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get some error to insert following_id, then i checked the development.log:

This is my false: follower_id = nil

```
[1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 9]]
[1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "11"]]
[1m[36mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "relations" ("created_at", "follower_id", "following_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Thu, 23 Oct 2014 07:19:22 UTC +00:00], ["follower_id", nil], ["following_id", 11], ["updated_at", Thu, 23 Oct 2014 07:19:22 UTC +00:00]]
```

I wan it to become: follower_id = 9, change between line 1 and 2

```
[1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "9"]]
[1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "11"]]
[1m[36mSQL (3.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "relations" ("created_at", "follower_id", "following_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Thu, 23 Oct 2014 07:19:22 UTC +00:00], ["follower_id", 9], ["following_id", 11], ["updated_at", Thu, 23 Oct 2014 07:19:22 UTC +00:00]]`
```

**So,How can i change it to be true???Some thing wrong with my code??Please help me!**

*This is my User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :pass, :username
  # Who am I following?
  has_many :relations, :foreign_key => :follower_id
  has_many :following, :through => :relations 
  # Who am I followed by?
  has_many :relations, :class_name => "Relation", :foreign_key => :following_id
  has_many :followers, :through => :relations

  validates :username, :pass, :presence => true
  validates :username, :pass, :length => { :minimum => 4 }
  validates :username, :uniqueness => true
```

*the relation model

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :following, :class_name => "User"
end
```

*relation controller

```
 class RelationController < ApplicationController
  def create
    follow = User.find(params[:relation][:following_id])
    @current_user.following << follow
    redirect_to follow
  end
```

*my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include WelcomeHelper
  before_filter :set_current_user

  private

  def set_current_user
    @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

*my action view

```
<h2><%= @user.username%><br /></h2>
<%= @user.pass%><br />
<% if  @current_user && @current_user != @user %>
  <% if @current_user.following.include?(@user) %>
    <%= link_to "Unfollow", 
      relation_path(@current_user.relation_for(@user)), 
      :method => :delete %>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_for @relation do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :following_id, :value => @user.id %>
      <%= f.submit "Follow" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<br>
<ul>
  <% @user.following.each do |u| %>
    <li><%= link_to u.username, u %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
Followed By
<ul>
  <% @user.followers.each do |u| %>
    <li><%= link_to u.username, u %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

This is my action to insert following_id

```
def create
    follow = User.find(params[:relation][:following_id])
    @current_user.following << follow
    redirect_to follow
  end
```

and my following_id has been sent

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"DIY42kGR9fZ54Pub+CDMuNNaHZ0aFnzSiWrkOFRBsdE=",
 "relation"=>{"following_id"=>"11"},
 "commit"=>"Follow"}
```

Comment: you need to provide a better description of your error. Can you post the code that generates the error? (can you point it?) Is it a problem because you get params that you don't expect? Please be more descriptive or there will not be way to help you. The queries you posted are the same, except that in one an id is a string instead of a number, which doesn't matter to rails. Is that causing a problem to you because you are doing some kind of parsing?

Comment: Thanks you, i will edit my post. When i click follow in action view, my following_id(11) has been sent, but it wasn't insert into my curent_user(9).following. In user.following.each, the following_id(11) has appeared (?????). It must be current_user.id(9) in user.followers.each, and nothing in user.following.each. Then i check development.log,  the follower_id is nil. 
Sorry, my english so bad!

Comment: I have my mistake in User model in line 4 and 7 :)), you can help me to change it. i make same relations